# Swiping between fragments: how to highlight tab?

Tags: android, tabs, swipe, highlight

I'm editing the source code of my friend's app and i'm trying to figure out how to deal with fragments. In the app i have an activity with 3 tab and when i click on one of them the selected tab become highlighted. This not happen when i switch from a tab to another doing swiping on the screen. How to edit the code to add this possibility?

```
public class ViewMyPage extends FragmentActivity{

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();  
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewmerchant);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("id", getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,SchedaMerchant.class.getName(),b));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,DescrizioneMerchant.class.getName(),b));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,ListaRecensioni.class.getName(),b));

        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonscheda);
        final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondesc);
        final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonrec);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                mPager.setCurrentItem(0);   // go to first tab
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1);   // go to second tab
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
                mPager.setCurrentItem(2);   // go to third tab
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
   // fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
   private List<Fragment> fragments;

   // constructor
   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
      super(fm);
      this.fragments = fragments;
   }

   // return access to fragment from position, required override
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return this.fragments.get(position);
   }

   // number of fragments in list, required override
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return this.fragments.size();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
            } else if (position == 1) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
            } else if (position == 2) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_11));
                button1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent_black_hex_8));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
});
```

Sorry for my post...